# Proving that a set $F \subset A$ is closed in $(A,d)$ if and only if $F = A \cap C$, where $C$ is closed in $(M,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I need to proof that, given a metric space $(M,d)$ and a subset $A \subset M$ that:

> A set $F \subset A$ is closed in $(A,d)$ if and only if $F = A \cap C$, where $C$ is closed in $(M,d)$

I have tried alot of things, but I can't seem to make it work. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,

K. Kamal.

Comment: Think about this: If $C$ is closed in $M$, then $A\cap C$ is closed in $A$.

Comment: Assume $F$ is closed in $A$. Then $A\setminus F$ is open in $A$. Therefore, there exists an open $U$ such that $A\setminus F = U\cap A$. Let $C := M\setminus U$. Then $F = A\setminus(A\setminus F) = A\setminus (U\cap A) = A\cap (U\cap A)^c = A\cap (U^c\cup A^c) = A\cap C$.

Comment: @M.Lobo That is one of the claims that has to be proved...

Comment: @amsmath How do you know that such an open set $U$ exists?

Comment: @K.Kamal Because that is the usual definition of being relatively open. Or how have you defined that a set is open in $A$?

Comment: @amsmath You are using the thesis for prove the thesis.

Comment: @M.Lobo Nope. I am using the definition of relative openness in order to prove a claim on relative closedness. Actually, that what you blame me for is what you proposed yourself in your first comment: proving the thesis by using the thesis.

Comment: @amsmath Sure. You are correct. I'am wrong.

Comment: @M.Lobo Now, you got it right. ;-)

Comment: @amsmath I see, thanks!

Comment: @amsmath ...LOL

Comment: Well, yes. Two dumbheads patting on each other's backs... See John Griffin's answer. LOL!

Answer (score 0):

amsmath's comment is the "best" way to do it if you have seen the definition of relative openness. However, since you are working with metric spaces, I'm not convinced that you have. Let's see if we can do it with sequences.

We use the definition that if $E$ is a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$, then $\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}x\in\cl(E)$ iff there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$ which converges to $x$.

We will use $\cl_A$ to denote the closure of a set in $(A,d)$ (which should technically be $(A,d|_{A\times A})$), and $\cl_M$ to denote the closure of a set in $(M,d)$.

Suppose $F=A\cap C$, where $C$ is closed in $(M,d)$. In order to show that $F$ is closed in $(A,d)$, we must show that $F\supseteq \cl_A(F)$. That is, we need to prove that if $x\in A$ such that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $F$ which converges to $x$ in $(A,d)$, then $x\in F$.
Observe that $(x_n)$ also converges to $x$ in $(M,d)$.
Since $(x_n)$ is in $F=A\cap C$ and $C$ is closed in $(M,d)$, then its limit point must be in $\cl_M(C)=C$. Thus $x\in A\cap C=F$, as desired.

Conversely, assume $F$ is closed in $(A,d)$. We wish to find a closed set $C$ in $(M,d)$ such that $F=A\cap C$. Take $C:=\cl_M(F)$. Then clearly $F\subseteq A\cap C$.
For the other inclusion, fix $x\in A\cap C$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in C= \cl_M(F)$, so there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $F$ which converges to $x$ in $(M,d)$. Since $(x_n)$ is in $F\subseteq A$ and $x\in A$, we have that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in $(A,d)$. Therefore $x\in \cl_A(F)=F$.